# posting html content to controller method removes part of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

This is the js function:

```
    var onContentChange = function () {
        var content =   
          $("#blogpost-content").data("kendoEditor").value($("#value").val());
        console.log(content);
        $http.post("/Map/SaveBlogPostContent?destinationId=" + 
           $("#currentDestinationId").val() + 
           "&blogPostId=" + $("#currentBlogPost").val() + "&content=" + content)
                .then(onSaveBlogPostContent, onError);
    }
```

This method is triggered on change of a textarea.
When it hits the console.log it writes out the correct text that is currently in the textarea but when it posts the data to my controller method it only receives a bit of the content.
Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible you have 'illegal characters' in your textarea, try to escape the content variable, change it like so:

```
var onContentChange = function () {
    var content = $("#blogpost-content").data("kendoEditor").value($("#value").val());
    console.log(content);
    $http.post("/Map/SaveBlogPostContent?destinationId=" + encodeURIComponent($("#currentDestinationId").val()) + "&blogPostId=" + encodeURIComponent($("#currentBlogPost").val()) + "&content=" + encodeURIComponent(content))
            .then(onSaveBlogPostContent, onError);
}
```

The encodeURIComponent() is the important part there.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a get and not a post, there are limits to the length of data you can send in the get request, it will depend by browser. you also want to make sure you dont have any characters that need to be escaped. eg. charters used in the url such as ? or & or /.  you can escape these by using.

```
var contentToPass = encodeURIComponent(content);
```

see here [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var onContentChange = function () {
    var content =   
    $("#blogpost-content").data("kendoEditor").value($("#value").val());
    console.log(content);
    $http.post("/Map/SaveBlogPostContent", {
       destinationId: $("#currentDestinationId").val(),
       blogPostId: $("#currentBlogPost").val(),
       content: content
    }).then(onSaveBlogPostContent, onError);
}
```